# Hybris - overriding existing unique attributes of an Item Type to make them non-unique

Tags: attributes, overriding, unique, sap-commerce-cloud

In my hybris application, I wanted to override my CustomerReview item type so that its attributes **product** and **user** are not unique anymore.

The uniqueness of these attributes are declared in the relationships between CustomerReview and Product/User. I tried adding the relationship declaration again to my **extname-items.xml**  file and set the appropriate unique="false" attributes, as follows:

```
<relation generate="false" localized="false" code="ReviewToUserRel" autocreate="false">
    <sourceElement type="User" qualifier="user" cardinality="one">
        <modifiers write="false" initial="true" optional="false" unique="false" />
    </sourceElement>
    <targetElement type="CustomerReview" qualifier="customerReviews" cardinality="many">
        <modifiers write="false" initial="true" />
    </targetElement>
</relation>
```

This doesn't do the trick though. After I rebuild the application and Update the Running System, the **user** and **product** attributes of a CustomerReview are still unique attributes.

So what's the best solution for this problem?

Comment: I've already posted this exact same question in the hybris wiki forum and got no answer yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that rewriting the relation will not override it.

Another way to solve it would be to add an attribute to the type and set that as unique. For instance `emailAddress`:

```
<itemtype code="CustomerReview" autocreate="false" generate="false">
    <attributes>
                <attribute type="java.lang.String" qualifier="email">
                    <persistence type="property" />
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" unique="true"/>
                </attribute>
     </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

Then you could have multiple reviews from the same user for the same product, as long as the `emailAddress` differs.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the relation will not overwrite the existing relation. Better create new item definition for CustomerReview and then relate this with product.